# How to completely override a remote branch, with local history and files?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I was given this weird task:
Use an existing remote repository(on Azure), for a totally new project. Meaning, they want to keep the repo(for some reason..), but I need to completely purge all of its contents and history.

then, I add it as a remote repo to some local repo and override everything.

How can this be done? I know i can use `git reset <first commit id>` in the remote branch, but this would still keep the first commit.

Is there any "brute force" way to achieve this? Note that `git push --force` won't do it because it would still keep existing files that have no conflict with the new ones.

Comment: But `git push --force` *does* do it, because Git isn't about *files*, it's about *commits*. (The `--all` in the accepted answer just means "do that force-push for all branch names in the local repository.")

Comment: I agree this is a weird ask. If you're blowing away the history, the only reason I can think to do this instead of deleting that repo and creating a new one, is to avoid having to setup security on a new repo. Is that the reason?

Comment: @TTT To be honest i don't know. It's a repo set up by some external company. This is what they asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should, on you local repository:

1. `git remote add origin <REMOTE_URL>`
2. `git push --force --all`

The second instruction will rewrite all the history by the local one.

Comment: Glad to have helped you. Please, kindly accept my answer.